# Implement ArrayList Class Remove Method Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to implement a custom built ArrayList Class. We can't use arrayCopy. I need to be able to remove a string from the array and then move all the elements to the left by one index. My attempt is below, please help.

```
/****************************************************************************
 * Removes the string at the specified index from the list,
 * if it is present and shifts the remaining elements left.
 *
 * @param  str value to remove from list
 * @return the value removed from the list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if index is invalid
 */
    public String remove(int index){
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.myArray.length)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
        }
        else {
        String removed = this.myArray[index];
        this.myArray[index] = null;
        String [] temp = new String[this.myArray.length-1];
        for(int i = 0; i<this.myArray.length; i++){
        if (this.myArray[i] != null){
            temp[i] = this.myArray[i];
        }
    }
        return removed;
    }
    }
```

I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at `temp[i] = this.myArray[i]`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I keep getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: What line are you getting the exception on?

Comment: temp[i] = this.myArray[i];

Comment: for(int i = index+1; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myArray[i-1] = myArray[i]
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a `temp` array with one fewer elements than `this.myArray`. Then you iterate over all of the indexes of `myArray` and use those indexes to write into `temp[i]`. The last one is out of bounds, since `temp` is one smaller.

A debugger would help you find this. You could also put a `System.out.println("about to access index " + i)` before any line that accesses an array, and see which line prints right before the exception. Then you just need to figure out which index you're about to access (it's right there in the stdout) and think about how big the array is that you're about to access.

Comment: I have a new problem now. It doesn't update the positions of the items in the array. So when I call myArray.remove(1) it leaves null at index one. Then when I call the method again, the size goes down by one, but the array doesn't change because the elements did not shift over.

Comment: @user3791101 I would strongly encourage you to take a pause and think things through one step at a time. What do you need to do to remove an element at index `i`? Imaging you had a bunch of sequentially-ordered boxes and wanted to remove an element from one as an array list does. What are the individual steps required? How would _you_ (not a computer) do it? Maybe even cut out some pieces of paper and give it a try. We could give you the answer, but thinking about how to get it is an important part of learning.

Comment: I would add elements one by one until I get to the index, then skip that and add elements to the index-1 to compensate for that missing value.

Comment: That's definitely a reasonable way. So, give that a try. If you have specific questions in coding that up, you can ask as a new question. But you should definitely give it a really solid try first, including trying to debug if something doesn't work as you expect. I know it feels like banging your head against a wall -- we've all been there -- but things like this really do make you a better programmer. At some point you'll have to be able to debug your programs. Better to learn as you go, rather than getting to the point of writing huge programs and suddenly needing to learn how to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The `temp` array is one shorter, so it can't fit everything.

You need to skip the desired index when copying the array.

The code below does this by using two different variables for the indices in the old and new arrays.

It skips incrementing one of them when the removed index is encountered.

```
public String remove(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.myArray.length) {
        // FYI, this would be thrown anyway; not sure if you need to do it
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds.");
    }
    String removed = this.myArray[index];
    String[] temp = new String[this.myArray.length - 1];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < this.myArray.length; i++){
        if (i != index) {
            temp[j++] = this.myArray[i];
        }
        // otherwise, j does not get incremented
    }
    this.myArray = temp; // don't forget this!
    return removed;
}
```

Comment: Oh whoops, I misread and didn't see your `j`. Sorry, ignore me. :)